# Webpack imported module - constructor error

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, mixins

In my Vue application I habe `main.js` which inside a Vue instace. THis Vue instance has one mixin with handled the `create` hook.

```
...
import Engine from './engine/EngineCore'
...
let mixin = {
      created: function () {

        this.$engine = window.CC_ENGINE_SHADOW = new Engine();

        this.$utils = {
          CommonUtils,
          ImagesUtils
        }
      }
    };

    new Vue({
      el: 'app',
      mixins: [mixin],
      components: {App},
      store
    });
```

`Engine` it's a simple javascript file which incapsulate some global functionalities for the whole application.

Running `npm run dev` the application starts but gives me this error:

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__engine_EngineCore___default.a is not a constructor
```

During this I did not touched anithing about Webpack and I'd like to understand deeply this error that I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Could you show use EngineCore.js file ?

Comment: Solved. Put on a Vue.js module... i'll update this answer later.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed answer? To my understanding the mixin is correctly resolved if exported from a separate JS file.

Comment: Can you explain the solution @grimi?